# Is there any result which states that if the output of these two functions is XOR'd, the XOR'd output is pseudorandom

Tags: pseudo-random-function, xor

Let $\mathbb{G}$ be a group of prime order $p$ with generator $g$. Suppose that I randomly pick $r_1,z_1 \leftarrow \mathbb{Z}_p$ and $r_2, z_2 \leftarrow \mathbb{Z}_p$ and $c \leftarrow \mathbb{G}$. Let $\alpha = g^{r_1z_1}g^{c}$ and $\beta = g^{r_2z_2}g^c$. By the semantic security of El-Gamal encryption, both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are indistinguishable from random numbers ... Suppose that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are encoded using bit-strings, has there been any result that their XOR is also indistinguishable from a random number or pseudorandom? i.e. $\alpha \oplus \beta$ is indistinguishable from a random number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> (…) is $\alpha\oplus\beta$ indistinguishable from a random number?

Note that we need to convert $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to bitstrings in order to apply [bitwise XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR). So really we compute $\underline\alpha\oplus\underline\beta$ where $\underline\gamma$ is is the notation for a uniquely defined representation of an arbitrary group element $\gamma$ as a fixed-size bitstring, and it's asked if $\underline\alpha\oplus\underline\beta$ is a random bitstring. The answer will depend on the representation used.

It's easy to find a clear counterexample with a familiar cryptographic group and representation, such a the subgroup of [quadratic residues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue) of the [multiplicative group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) modulo $(2p+1)$, when $p$ is a large random [Sophie Germain prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_and_Sophie_Germain_primes) of say 1999 bits¹ and leading bits `1010`, and the representation of group elements as 2000-bit bitstrings per [big-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) convention. $\underline\alpha$ and $\underline\beta$ are 2000-bit bitstrings with a marked bias towards `0` in the first two bits, and there is a similar (though lower) bias in the first  two bits of $\underline\alpha\oplus\underline\beta$.

On the other hand, if in the above we replace `1010` with `111…111` over say 200 bits², then $\underline\alpha$ will be indistinguishable from random except for representing an $\alpha$ that's a quadratic residue³. Despite this, and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ not being strictly independent⁴, I conjecture both effects are weak enough that $\underline\alpha\oplus\underline\beta$ is computationally indistinguishable from random.

For any representation of group elements as bitstring, we can devise another representation of the same size by applying a public efficiently computable and reversible Pseudo Random Permutation to the representation. The properties of the group remain, ElGamal encryption still works and is equally secure. And now, for any $p$ large enough that the DLP is hard, $\underline\alpha\oplus\underline\beta$ can be proven computationally indistinguishable from random using properties of the PRP.

---

¹ Such that ElGamal encryption is secure, which is implicit in the question.

² We may want to increase the bit size of $p$ slightly to compensate for the Discrete Logarithm Problem being slightly eased by $p$ being close to a power of two.

³ A characteristic that's efficiently testable by checking that the Legendre symbol $\left(\frac\alpha{2p+1}\right)\,\underset{\text{def}}=\,\alpha^p\bmod(2p+1)$ is $+1$

⁴ Notice that $\alpha^{-1}\beta\bmod(2p+1)$ is a slightly biased element of the group.